# Device the file or directory resides on

Tags: ansible

How to identify the device on which the file or directory resides?

[There is a stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html).
Among the results there is a ["Device the inode resides on"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/dev).

How can you map the *"Device the inode resides on"* to a partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one need to understand [What is the device of inode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079278/6771046) and [device number in `stat` command output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309947/6771046).

Then, for an example debug output

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    stat:
...
      dev: 2051
```

there is a Device ID with `2051` decimal but we would need it in HEX. According [How can I convert a decimal string to an hexadecimal string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61491339/6771046) a task like

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ '%#x' % result.stat.dev }}"
```

would report

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '0x803'
```

This needs to be split into major (`8`) and minor (`3`) device. Maybe start with

```yaml
"{{ ('%#x' % result.stat.dev).split('x') | last }}"
```

In an other task it would be necessary to gather the result of

```bash
~/test$ ls -al /dev/sd*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  2 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda2
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  3 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda3
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  4 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda4
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  5 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sda5
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sdb
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 32 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sdc
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 33 Feb 29 00:01 /dev/sdc1
```

and parse it accordingly since `ansible_facts.device_links` `ansible_facts.devices` do not collect and hold that kind of information.

Depending on the infrastructure `lsblk --output` formatted for necessary information only might be easier.

```bash
lsblk -o NAME,MAJ:MIN,MOUNTPOINT
NAME   MAJ:MIN MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0
├─sda1   8:1   /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2   /boot
├─sda3   8:3   /
├─sda4   8:4   /tmp
└─sda5   8:5   [SWAP]
sdb      8:16  /var/lib/pgsql/16/data
sdc      8:32
└─sdc1   8:33  /var
sr0     11:0
```

Or according [How to get a device/partition name of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404063/6771046) just

```bash
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

  11        0    1234567 sr0
   8       32   12345678 sdc
   8       33   12345678 sdc1
   8        0  123456789 sda
   8        1     123456 sda1
   8        2     123456 sda2
   8        3   12345678 sda3
   8        4   12345678 sda4
   8        5    1234567 sda5
   8       16    1234567 sdb
```

From here we can see Major 8 (SCSI) and Minor 3 is `/dev/sda3`. And "*How to find out what's behind the major number?*", see in example [Linux : Major and Minor device numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73988/) or [Major and minor numbers of a partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256836/266568).

An example task with [zero padded fields from text file](https://superuser.com/a/203159/754490)

```yaml
  - name: Gather Custom Fact - Partition major minor numbers
    shell:
      cmd: |
        tail -n +3 /proc/partitions | awk '{ printf "%s: %02i%02i\n", $4,$1,$2 }'
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false
    register: partmajmin

  - debug:
      var: (partmajmin.stdout | from_yaml)
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  (partmajmin.stdout | from_yaml):
    sda: 0800
    sda1: 0801
    sda2: 0802
    sda3: 0803
    sda4: 0804
    sda5: 0805
    sdb: 0816
    sdc: 0832
    sdc1: 0833
    sr0: 1100
```

The numbers are accessible as well transformable into integer in example as follow

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: (partmajmin.stdout | from_yaml).sda3 | int(base=16)
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  (partmajmin.stdout | from_yaml).sda3 | int(base=16): '2051'
```

Finally, a task

```yaml
  - name: Device an inode can reside on
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.key }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', (partmajmin.stdout | from_yaml)) }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.value | int(base=16) }}"
```

will report

```yaml
TASK [Device an inode can reside on] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=2099) =>
  msg: sdc1
ok: [localhost] => (item=2098) =>
  msg: sdc
ok: [localhost] => (item=2052) =>
  msg: sda4
ok: [localhost] => (item=1100) =>
  msg: sr0
ok: [localhost] => (item=2053) =>
  msg: sda5
ok: [localhost] => (item=2050) =>
  msg: sda2
ok: [localhost] => (item=2048) =>
  msg: sda
ok: [localhost] => (item=2070) =>
  msg: sdb
ok: [localhost] => (item=2049) =>
  msg: sda1
ok: [localhost] => (item=2051) =>
  msg: sda3
```

Answer (score 0):

*supplement: for a minor number must take the last two digits of the number*

---

File: `/path/to/file1`
linux stat: `device 8/1`
ansible device stat: `dev: 2049`

2049 (DEC) = 801 (HEX) --> `8`.`01` --> `8`/`01` (HEX) = `8`/`1` (DEC)

---

File: `/path/to/file2`
linux stat: `device 259/2`
ansible device stat: `dev: 66306`

66306 (DEC) = 10302 (HEX) --> `103`.`02` --> `103`/`02` (HEX) = `259`/`2` (DEC)

---

File: `/path/to/file3`
linux stat: `device 254/1`
ansible device stat: `dev: 65025`

65025 (DEC) = FE01 (HEX) --> `FE`.`01` --> `FE`/`01` (HEX) = `254`/`1` (DEC)

---

File: `/path/to/file4`
linux stat: `device 0/45`
ansible device stat: `dev: 45`

45 (DEC) = 2D (HEX) --> `0`.`2D` --> `0`/`2D` (HEX) = `0`/`45` (DEC)